# Kurdish language Latex

Tags: languages

Kurdish (sorani)  is similar arabic and persian language , its written from the right to left, and most of the letter is same with some different ( less than 10). Now there is solution for written arabic and persian. My question , How can I able to solve this problem? did I need to create kurdish package ? and is there is open source language which is possible  to edit .

Comment: If you have a system font that covers the language and use xselatex (rather than pdflatex0 it should just work if you load the font using the `fontspec`  package. There may also be specific Kurdish babel or polyglossia setups to define fixed strings such as "table of contents" in the language, I am not sure. If you posted some text in the script and suggested a commonly available font people might suggest some tex markup.

Comment: This package catalog entry says it supports kurdish http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/help/Catalogue/entries/arabxetex.html

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your link help, the only issue in this case I have to write in Latin in this case and later it will change to kurdish. but there is another question. as you said in your first comment , maybe there is "kurdish babel" which is more easier to use. thanks

Comment: there's a `babel` plugin for kurmanji.  it sounds as if it's not what you're looking for, since kurmanji (according to the package details) is written in a latin script.  `polyglossia` doesn't (that i can see) mention any kurdish language.

Comment: @henry `arabxetex` will by default read unicode -- there's no fiddling needed.  i recommend you have a look at that, too.  it would be good to hear if you get anywhere with these things: i can distill comments into the ctan catalogue, if they would help others.

Comment: @wasteofspace thanks for your comment, I already worked on "arabtex" and the result was not promising , I tried to use "arabxetex" but first I have to change pdflatex0 since as David said  and I also noticed that it make issue with "arabxetex" , I am using Mac and I am not sure its a good operating system to deal with this problem, meanwhile I will try to use "arabxetex" and hope we good good result.